# How to show Android Wear-like Menu from Activity?

Tags: android, wear-os

Notification Commands are shown as big blue buttons, once you go to them.

I think it could be great to show `Activity` menu in the same way in our activities.

Right now, once you call `.openOptionsMenu()`, a usual menu is shown.
[image: default menu]

So, is there a way to show Activity menu, as Notification commands?

[image: Notification menu]

Comment: "I think it could be great to show Activity menu in the same way in our activities." -- You think wrong. Android Wear UI was designed for tiny screens and quick interaction, while Options menus are designed for larger screens -- more information, fewer clicks, taps and swipes.

Comment: I should probably rephrase my question, because you got me wrong. I understand, that Wear UI is for tiny screens and quick actions. That's why I say "show Activity menu, as Notification commands". Google Glass works in the same way: instead of showing Android menus, [they show them as cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/immersions#creating_and_displaying_a_menu), which perfectly fits in their UI.

Answer (score 0):

This optional library has been created so we can use this sort of styling in our apps.
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'

It's got exactly the views your looking for.  Check out CircledImageView and the CardFragment.